# How to fix 404 error when using JsonHttpResponseHandler()?

Tags: java, android-studio

Trying to create a simple movie showtime mobile app. I've used the this method before in another class and it works fine but for some reason in this current class I get a 404 error.

```
client.get(String.format(VIDEO_URL, 209112), new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Headers headers, JSON json) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray results = json.jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                            if(results.length() == 0){
                                return;
                            }
                            String youtubeKey = results.getJSONObject(0).getString("key");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("DetailActivity", "Failed to parse JSON", e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Headers headers, String response, Throwable throwable) {
                        System.out.println("On failure again " +statusCode  + " response: " + response);
                    }
                });
```

I have the dependency line for it in my gradle file as well.

```
implementation 'com.codepath.libraries:asynchttpclient:0.0.9'
```

This is the onFailure message I get

```
On failure again 404 response: {"status_code":34,"status_message":"The resource you requested could not be found."}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 error is a server-side error.

[404 not found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

The problem should be irrelevant to your android code. You may check if the url you are requesting really exists.

EDIT:
You may log the url and check whether the format is correct

Comment: Yesyou were right, I had a typo in the VIDEO_URL. Thanks